# Server can't send the message from one client to the list of clients in python socket programming

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, client-server

The clients are able to connect to the server successfully but when I send the message "!sendall" from one client, other clients in the list does not receive this message "Sending this to All!". I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Please assist. Thank you.

****server.py****

```
import socket
import os
from _thread import *

ServerSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ServerSocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

host = '192.168.3.248'
port = 9368
ThreadCount = 0
ipList = []
conList = []

try:
    ServerSocket.bind((host, port))
except socket.error as e:
    print(str(e))

print('Waiting for a Connection..')
ServerSocket.listen(5)


def threaded_client(connection, addr):
    connection.send(str.encode('Welcome to the Server'))
    while True:
        data = connection.recv(2048)
        print(data.decode())
        if data.decode()[0:2] == '!q':
            connection.close()
            break;

        elif data.decode()[0:8] == '!sendall':
            for ipAddr in ipList:
                if addr != ipAddr:
                    connection.sendto(b'Sending this to All!', ipAddr)

        else:
            reply = 'Server Says: ' + data.decode('utf-8')
            connection.sendall(str.encode(reply))

        if not data:
            break
    connection.close()


while True:
    Client, address = ServerSocket.accept()
    if address not in ipList:
        ipList.append(address)

    if Client not in conList:
        conList.append(Client)
    print('Connected to: ' + address[0] + ':' + str(address[1]))
    print("Added IP to the list")
    start_new_thread(threaded_client, (Client, address, ))
    ThreadCount += 1
    print('Thread Number: ' + str(ThreadCount))
ServerSocket.close()
```

**client.py**

```
import socket

ClientSocket = socket.socket()
host = '192.168.3.248'
port = 9368

print('Waiting for connection')
try:
    ClientSocket.connect((host, port))
except socket.error as e:
    print(str(e))

Response = ClientSocket.recv(1024)
while True:
    Input = input('Say Something: ')
    ClientSocket.send(str.encode(Input))
    Response = ClientSocket.recv(1024)
    print(Response.decode('utf-8'))

ClientSocket.close()
```

----Output From Server----

```
Waiting for a Connection..
Connected to: 192.168.3.114:49968
Added IP to the list
Thread Number: 1
Connected to: 192.168.3.248:30750
Added IP to the list
Thread Number: 2
```

---- Output from one client -----

```
Waiting for connection
Say Something: Hello
Server Says: Hello
Say Something: !sendall      
Sending this to All!  <---------- The other connected clients doesn't receive this message, which they are supposed to receieve
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you're starting a new thread for each client in the line

```
start_new_thread(threaded_client, (Client, address, ))
```

Only one client is connected to each thread, you'll have to use a `Queue` to pass information to each thread.